# Proving that a function is surjective and the equality holds

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

This is exercise 2.76 (ii) from Rotman's "Introduction to the theory of Groups".[image]

I was able to do (i) but I have no idea how to proceed to prove (ii).

Comment: Maybe focus on a simpler sub-problem: suppose $n = 2$. Now, in general, to show a function is surjective, we should take an arbitrary element of the codomain and try to find an element of the domain which maps to it. Have you tried this? If so, where did you get stuck? Also, a hint -- when we have coprime integers in group theory, it's almost always useful to apply Bézout's Lemma.

Comment: Yes I've tried to think when n=2 but I arrived at no conclusion, and I also don't see where to use Bézout's Lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that:
$$[G:H_1\cap\dots \cap H_n]=[G:H_i][H_i:H_1\cap\dots \cap H_n]$$

Hence $[G:H_i] \;\; | \;\; [G:H] \; \forall i$, but they are coprime so:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} [G:H_i] \;\; | \;\; |G/H_1\cap\dots \cap H_n| $$

But $G/(H_1\cap\dots \cap H_n)\sim Im(\varphi) \leq G/H_1\times\dots \times G/H_n \;$ by first isomorphism theorem. So $|G/H_1\cap\dots \cap H_n|=|Im(\varphi)|\;\; | \;G/H_1\times\dots \times G/H_n;|= \prod_{i=1}^{n} [G:H_i] \implies \prod_{i=1}^{n} [G:H_i] = |G/H_1\cap\dots \cap H_n|$.